# Operator overloading, Rvalues, C++

Tags: c++, copy, operator-overloading, move-semantics, rvalue

Consider a struct

```
template<typename T, size_t N>
struct Something {
    std::array<T,N> args;

    // Some constructors

};
```

Now let's overload `=` operator for `Something<T>`. In fact I can implement it two ways.

**First Way**

```
Something& operator=(const Something& rhs){
    // an implementation with copy semantics
}

Something& operator=(Something&& rhs) {
    // an implementation with move semantics
}
```

**Second Way**

```
Something& operator=(Something rhs){
    // implement with move semantics
}
```

So, my question is what is the *most standard way* and the *most optimal way* to do overloading *First Way* or *Second Way*?

Comment: Are you asking in general, or for you particular case? Generally, the second way may not be optimal.

Comment: It depend on you purpose , the choice of pointer refer and memory copy

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For this particular case you should not implement the assignment operator. The compiler does that already for you:

```
#include <array>
#include <cstddef>

template<typename T, size_t N>
struct Something {
    std::array<T,N> args;
};

int main() {
    Something<int,42> a;
    Something<int,42> b;
    a = b;
}
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/E8zPPc)

For the general case I refer you to [What are the basic rules and idioms for operator overloading?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4421706/what-are-the-basic-rules-and-idioms-for-operator-overloading). And consider that not everything can be moved and not everything can be copied. Moreover, sometimes a move is just a copy. Hence, it depends.

Comment: actually I was asking in general)

Comment: @HrantNurijanyan you wanted to ask for the general case, but you did ask for this example ;)

Comment: Couldn't you use `std::array::size_type` and (then) don't need to include cstddef?